# Repeat stream when done

Tags: flutter, dart

hello I am using a stream on my app to get some data. at the end of data the stream stop, what i want is to start again every time stream is done

```
  final stream =  Stream.periodic(kDuration, (count) => count)
      .take(kLocations.length);

stream.listen((value) => newLocationUpdate(value)
```

I was searching for hours and didnt find a good solution

Comment: Why are you calling `.take(kLocations.length)`?

Comment: the code was from here https://github.com/gauris26/flutter_animarker

Comment: That doesn't really answer my question. If you want the stream to continue streaming, just remove the `.take()` call. If you want the count to reset to 0, modify your function `(count) => count` to be `(count) => count % 10` for example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Calling `.take(kLocations.length)` will cause the stream to close once that number of elements have been emitted. For example:

```dart
final stream = Stream.periodic(kDuration, (count) => count).take(3);
stream.listen(print);  // prints 0, 1, 2, then stops
```

If instead, you want this to repeat (i.e. emit 0, 1, 2, 0, 1, 2, etc), you can use the modulus operator (`%`):

```dart
final stream = Stream.periodic(kDuration, (count) => count % 3);
stream.listen(print);  // prints 0, 1, 2, 0, 1, 2, 0, 1, 2, ...
```